# how i can make slideshow, get information(image, title , content) from database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make a slideshow, get information (image, title , content) from a database for the site php, html, and css?

I want to make a slideshow for the last ten posts(products) or features posts (products) on header site.  How can make this?  Thanks.

So this script slideshow, I want to replaсe instead source (image, title , descriptions) from database, from the table posts.

```
<a href="#" class="show">
    <img src="images/flowing-rock.jpg" alt="Flowing Rock" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Flowing Rock</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. "/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/grass-blades.jpg" alt="Grass Blades" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Grass Blades</h3>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/ladybug.jpg" alt="Ladybug" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Ladybug</h3>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/lightning.jpg" alt="Lightning" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Lightning</h3>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/lotus.jpg" alt="Lotus" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Lotus</h3>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/mojave.jpg" alt="Mojave" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Mojave</h3>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt."/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/pier.jpg" alt="Pier" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Pier</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/sea-mist.jpg" alt="Sea Mist" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Sea Mist</h3>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/stones.jpg" alt="Stone" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Stone</h3>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."/>
</a>
```

I want post indeasted link image, code php to get the image from the database, as well as the title and content, but I want make (do{ wile())}, to get only last ten products.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you haven't provided any details about your database structure... but let's cover the basics...

First, you need to perform a query that returns an array of 10 items (as arrays). Then you need to create a loop that outputs everything...

In MySQLi, you'd do something like this...

```
$objStmt = $this->objDb->prepare("
    SELECT image, imageAlt, imageTitle, imageRel FROM posts WHERE [some criteria is met];
");
$objStmt->bind_param([some params to bind]);

$objStmt->execute();
$objStmt->bind_result($image, $imageAlt, $imageTitle, $imageRel);

$arrItems = array();

while ($objRow = $objStmt->fetch()) {
    $arrItem = array();
    $arrItem['image'] = $image;
    $arrItem['imageAlt'] = $imageAlt;
    $arrItem['imageTitle'] = $imageTitle;
    $arrItem['imageRel'] = $imageRel;
    array_push($arrItems, $arrItem);
    unset($arrItem);
}
```

And then...

```
    foreach ($arrItems as $arrItem) {
        printf('<a href="#" class="show"><img src="%s" alt="%s" width="580" height="360" title="%s" alt="" rel="%s"/></a>', $arrItem['image'], $arrItem['imageAlt'], $arrItem['imageTitle'], $arrItem['imageRel']);
    }
```